# Logging of multiple appenders to same logger

Tags: log4j

I want to implement same logfile for different appenders ..Is it possible to do so?or should i have to use different log files?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

To be on the safe side it is probably better not to do this as it could lead to synchronization issues, deadlock or corrupt log files.

However, [logback](http://logback.qos.ch) (log4j's successor) allows this, in [prudent](http://logback.qos.ch/manual/appenders.html#prudent) mode.

Another alternative, is to have your multiple appenders log to a single `SocketAppender` and have the receiving socket log to a file.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know log4j, but log4net has `ForwardingAppender` and `BufferingForwardingAppender`, and I guess it's probably similar.

So presumably you could have multiple ForwardingAppenders that all forward to the same FileAppender.